# Second gen nano won't connect to computer

Tags: itunes, ipod, windows

I have a second gen nano that will not charge or connect to the computer. I see it charging when the screen is on, but when it goes to sleep, it stops charging. I've left the thing on overnight and it's on half battery life. Usually you'll see the little battery with the lightning bolt over it when it's sleeping and charging. That will come up once in a while but promptly go away again.

So I figure the thing's shot and I need to immediately get the music off of the ipod. I try plugging the thing into my Windows 7 computer and it tells me that the device driver cannot be found. I go through everything that Apple tells me to do (reinstall driver, a whole bunch of USB stuff) to no avail. iTunes won't recognize it unless the computer recognizes it so I can't put it into disk mode to get the songs off.

This is my last step before taking it to an Apple store; any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have done everything you can before resorting to really trying to restore it (which will wipe it). Bear in mind that an Apple store will probably wipe it or (if under warranty) replace it.